# Build variant kind of a capability in UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

Is there a build variant kind of a feature available in UWP as there is in Android?
Or is there any other way of creating configurable builds for UWP

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I'm trying to get the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927615/uwp-visual-studio-how-to-make-different-builds-variants) answered...

Comment: @user1195883 - I was mostly looking for a multi branding feature for which I referred this link : http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1087]

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, you have the concept of "Build Configurations" which default to a few different ones as default (ARM, Debug, Release + a few variants).

There is a good article on undersanding build configurations here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am still not able to figure out for a particular build, how to set which project items will be included.

Comment: In each of the build configurations, when you're in teh window named "Configuration Manager", you just cross out the things you want in/out of that particular build. Very easy.

Comment: Isnt that for architecture specific build configurations,in configuration Manager,?