# UWP / Visual Studio: How to make different builds variants?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, uwp

I need to have three different build variants (flavors) of my UWP app that can be installed parallel: one for production, one for testing and one for development. They obviously need to share the same code base but have different constants like backend URLs and API keys.

In Android Studio this can be done using "build variants" and in Xcode this can be done using "schemes". What's the Visual Studio equivalent of those?

Maybe "build configurations" using the Configuration Manager as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx is the way to go. By default I have a Debug and a Release configuration. Would it be correct to rename those to Production-Debug and Production-Release and then create Testing-Debug, Testing-Release, Development-Debug and Development-Release? What I don't understand though:

1. Will that allow me to install Production, Testing and Development parallel on the same device?
2. How do I know which flavor I'm running in code (in order to get different properties, constants)?

**EDIT:** This is about UWP apps, not about web apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web.Debug.config vs. Web.Release.config running web app in localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921566/web-debug-config-vs-web-release-config-running-web-app-in-localhost)

Comment: I would be very glad if you can show me where is Web.Debug.Config within the scope of UWP app

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf I think web.config is not relevant here, I'm talking about UWP apps.

Comment: You are right , [read this](http://amadeusw.com/iot/custom-resource-files-in-uwp-windows-10) On UWP, there is no access to System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf Thanks. But that is not what I'm looking for. I need a configuration that allows me to have "three different build variants (flavors) of my UWP app that can be installed parallel".

Answer (score 5):

You can just use conditionals like this:

```
<AppxManifest Include="Manifest.Debug.xml"
              Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</AppxManifest>
<AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest"
              Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</AppxManifest>
```

Comment: where does the code go exactly, within `Package.appxmanifest` ?

Comment: @Allstar, no, you make a debug variant of `Package.appxmanifest`, and name it `Manifest.Debug.xml`. The code above goes into the `.csproj` (UWP) or `.wapproj` (packaged desktop app).

Comment: thanks @LOST, it works. I just had to change the Name under `Identity` in the new manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Double click on Package.appxmanifest file in your project.

Select Packaging label and enter different Package names for different cases.

Store each of variants.

Your PC gonna think these are different UWP apps.

Comment: But how can I assign the different appxmanifest files to the build configurations?

Comment: Seems like you can't or I didn't dig that far. It was like an alternative variant. Also you may try make branches of your project and merge code among them.

Comment: Then let me try to dig that far... :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution using this guide: http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=1087

I basically ended up having an appxmanifest (renamed to appxmanifest2 since you can only have one appxmanifest per project) per build configuration and then in the build events "pre-build event command line" I'm copying the one I need into the project root.

For the constants I'm using pre-processor conditional compilation symbols.

Comment: You need not rename the other appxmanifest. Simply change the 'Build Action' property of it to 'None'. Since you are copying it to the project root in pre-build events, finally you would have only one appxmanifest in your project folder.